# per-cpu variable definition in Linux kernel 2.6.27

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

In 2.6.27 there is the macro DEFINE_PER_CPU(type, variable) to define per-cpu variables.

I am able to define a variable in the global scope using this macro. But if its a variable inside a structure I see an error when compiling..

for ex:

```
struct port_stats {
    ... ....
    DEFINE_PER_CPU(long *, stats);
}
```

The error I see is..

***error: section attribute not allowed for 'per_cpu__stats'***

The same definition is ok if its outside the structure. Not sure what this error means. Any suggestions ?

Comment: You cannot put `DEFINE_PER_CPU` inside structure because of various reasons, the most obvious one is that it is macro that expands to declaration with attributes and cannot put attributes for member of a structure.

You could try something like
`
struct port_stats {
... ....
};
DEFINE_PER_CPU(struct port_stats, pstat);`

Comment: @Sundar In later versions which support __percpu attribute its possible to specify the percpu attribute only for some members of a structure. Looks like it doesn't work only with the macro based definition in older kernels ?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to define a per-cpu variable within a `struct` in the Linux kernel, you need to make it a pointer to the desired type (so, in this case `long **`) with the `__percpu` attribute:

```
struct port_stats {
    ... ....
    long __percpu **stats;
}
```

(On older kernels that lack the `__percpu` macro, just declare it as `long **stats;` with a comment that it is a pointer to an array of per-cpu variables).

Then when you create an instance of the structure, allocate the per-cpu variables with `alloc_percpu()` (which can fail):

```
pstats->stats = alloc_percpu(long *);

if (!pstats->stats)
    return -ENOMEM;
```

To then access the percpu instance, you need to use `get_cpu()` and `put_cpu()`:

```
long **stats;

stats = per_cpu_ptr(pstats->stats, get_cpu());

/* Read or write *stats, the per-cpu (long *) value for this cpu */

put_cpu();
```

When you free the structure, you must also execute `free_percpu(pstats->stats);` as well.

Comment: 2.6.27 doesn't have the __percpu attribute.

Comment: Ahh yes sorry, this answer applies to current (as of writing) kernels.  `alloc_percpu()` and `per_cpu_ptr()` were in 2.6.27, though - you can just leave off the `__percpu` designation, it's only for additional type-safety checking anyway.